# No response is seen in browser console for ajax call taking more than 2 minutes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am currently working on a spring/backbone js app. I am making an ajax call to the server . For small amount of data everything works as expected but when i try to process all the data in the data that is there in that mysql table it takes  a minimum of 2 minutes and can take more than 10 minutes for server to process it and send the response. It sends the same data  as the small data set( a Boolean to know whether the processing was successful or not) but in the chrome console i don't see any response and the ajax success handler doesn't get invoked.

I thought it was timeout issue but even when i gave a large timeout value (eg., 99999999999) then also the nothing got invoked neither the success handler nor the error handler. Here is the code sample. When "allDistricts" is true the server process all data and only then the problem occurs not when i provide some comma separated values to process. I would really appreciate some help in figuring out this one.

```
$("#update-summary").off("click.updateSummary").on("click.updateSummary",function(){
            $("#update-summary").prop("disabled",true);
            var allDistricts =$("#all-districts").is(":checked");
            var districtIds = [];
            if(!allDistricts){
                var districtIdsInput = $("#districtId").val().split(',');
                districtIds = districtIdsInput.map(function(districtId){
                    return districtId.trim();
                }).filter(function(districtId){
                    if(districtId){
                        return districtId;
                    }
                });
                if(!districtIds.length){
                    return;
                }
                for(var i =0 ;i < districtIds.length;i++){
                    if(parseInt(districtIds[i])!=districtIds[i]){
                        $(".update-district-summary-status-message").text("Please enter valid district IDs");
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            $(".update-district-summary-status-message").text("");
                        },3000);
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
            $(".update-district-summary-status-message").text("Processing");
            $.ajax({
                url:"/secure/updateDistrictSummary",
                timeout:9999999999999,
                data:{
                    dIds:districtIds,
                    all:allDistricts
                }}).fail(function(error){
                    console.log(error);
                }).done(function(response){
                    $("#update-summary").prop("disabled",false);
                    if(response.status===true){
                        $(".update-district-summary-status-message").text("Updated Successfully for all districts");
                    }else if(response.status === false){
                        $(".update-district-summary-status-message").text("Update UnSuccessful for all districts");
                    }else{
                        var resultString  = response.failed.slice(1).reduce(function(previous,current){
                            return previous+" ,"+current;
                        },response.failed[0]+"");
                        $(".update-district-summary-status-message").text("Update UnSuccessful For district Id(s) - "+resultString);
                    }
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $(".update-district-summary-status-message").text("");
                    },3000);
                });
```

Attaching screen shots of response --
[response time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fq5Y8.png)
[blank response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvEIL.png)

Comment: What happens when you call the Java code directly ? Perhaps it just needs that much time to run.

Comment: Yes it takes some time to run but the problem is i don't see any response in the browser console even after the java code has finished running and the returned the response , whereas for processing time of around 10-20 sec i can see the response in the browser . The response for both the data set is same.

Comment: make a screen of the xhr call form your network tab,how large is your data  kb ,mb ,50mb, >50mb?

Comment: The response i send is just one Boolean "status":true/false indicating whether the processing was completed without any errors or not. It doesn't contain any other data.

Comment: your problem seem to be in the back-end where you process the data

Comment: But i have checked by putting breakpoints in method where the response is returned . There seems to be no error there as it returns the correct value after processing everything the exact same value as the small data set. Do you mean it has to do with spring ? Because the code works as expected.

Comment: Are you expecting output in the conjole ? Console like that accessible by using `console.log()` ? I suggest you do what @madalinivascu said and post it here. If you use Chrome you can create a socalled HAR and provide it here if the result is too big for a screenshot.

Comment: attached 2 screenshots .